# Probability certain class is the biggest in multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, multinomial-distribution

Suppose we have a multinomial distribution:
$$Pr(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, \dots, X_k = x_k)=\dfrac{n!}{x_1! x_2! \cdots x_k!} \cdot p_1^{x_1}\cdot p_2^{x_2} \cdots p_k^{x_k}$$

What is the probabilty that $X_1=max(X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots,X_k)$ ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Some context for this problem? Do you expect this to have a simple solution ?

Comment: Hi, I am combining multiple models where I take the majority vote to classify some data. So in my case $X_1$ would be the correct class and I want to know the probabily that the majority vote get it right based on $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ . I have no particular reason to think there would be a simple solution.